# Nested loops using Cocoon Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

So I'm building a recipe app where is user can create his own dish.

the problem im facing is in cocoon gem i have followed every step on their documentation but while creating the recipe the user is not able to see the nested form for ingredients. the form to fill in the ingredients just does not display. The main form works fine which has image, name and description. it saves displays perfectly. I'm trying to give all the chunks of code that I feel could have problem and could help you simulate my app. 
Thanks for the Help

code for the simple_form under file name -->  _form.html.erb

```
<div id="panel-body">
<%= f.input :image, input_html: {class: "form-control"} %>
<%= f.input :name, input_html: {class: "form-control"} %>
<%= f.input :description, input_html: {class: "form-control"} %>

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3>Ingredients</h3>
    <div id="Ingredients">
      <%= f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient| %>
        <%= render "ingredient_fields", f: ingredient %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :ingredients, class: "btn btn-default add-button" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

code for the ingredient_fields under the file name --> _ingredient_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="form-inline clearfix">
  <div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.input :name, input_html: {class: "form-input form-control"} %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: "btn btn-default form-button"%>
  </div>
</div>
```

code for the Recipe model

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :ingredients

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "450x250#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true

  validates :name, :description, :image, presence: true
end
```

code for Recipe controller

```
def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, :description, :image, ingredient_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
```

Comment: "it does not display" --> when you click the "Add" button nothing happens? Did you include the `cocoon.js`?

Comment: @nathanvda Thanks a lot thats exactly what the problem was. Stupid me!

Comment: However now the problem is that the show page is not displaying the ingredients. for which the code i have written is <% @car.ingredients.each do |ingredient| %> <li><%= ingredient.name %></li> <% end %>

Comment: I see in your `recipe_params` you have not specified `name` as an allowed parameter for an ingredient? If that is not the case, please ask in a separate question.

Comment: Im sorry i think i pasted a wrong code but i have edited now.

Comment: Seems like the problem is that the data is not being saved in the database and i have no idea why